# in responsive menu it puts two links on the same line

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, drop-down-menu

when I put a small screen the menu puts the link "dropdown" and the "about" on the same line. I wanted to put the "about" below the dropdown just like the others. It is only when the screen is small (when it is the size of a mobile phone), when the screen is large it works well,so to check it you should reduce the size of the browser screen.The problem is that it puts the "dropdown" and the "about" on the same line.

```js
/* Toggle between adding and removing the "responsive" class to topnav when the user clicks on the icon */
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
  }
}
```

```css
 /* Add a black background color to the top navigation */
.topnav {
  background-color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Style the links inside the navigation bar */
.topnav a {
  /*float: left;*/
  display: inline-flex;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

/* Add an active class to highlight the current page */
.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

/* Hide the link that should open and close the topnav on small screens */
.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

/* Dropdown container - needed to position the dropdown content */
.dropdown {
  /*float: left;*/
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-flex;
}

/* Style the dropdown button to fit inside the topnav */
.dropdown .dropbtn {
 
  font-size: 17px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  
}

/* Style the dropdown content (hidden by default) */
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

/* Style the links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

/* Add a dark background on topnav links and the dropdown button on hover */
.topnav a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
}

/* Add a grey background to dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

/* Show the dropdown menu when the user moves the mouse over the dropdown button */
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

/* When the screen is less than 600 pixels wide, hide all links, except for the first one ("Home"). Show the link that contains should open and close the topnav (.icon) */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child), .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: none;
  }
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

/* The "responsive" class is added to the topnav with JavaScript when the user clicks on the icon. This class makes the topnav look good on small screens (display the links vertically instead of horizontally) */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive a.icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown {float: left;}
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown-content {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
        <LINK REL=StyleSheet HREF="estilosMenu.css?<?php echo date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A'); ?>" TYPE="text/css">
        <script src="menu.js?<?php echo date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A'); ?>"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
         <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
            <a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
            <a href="#news">News</a>
            <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
            <div class="dropdown">
                <!--<a href="#news">Dropdown</a>-->
              <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown
                <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
              </button>
              <div class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                <a href="#">Link 3</a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <a href="#about">About</a>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
          </div> 
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dropdown is floated to the left, so the following item can be next to it. Setting the dropdown's `width` to `100%` as suggested in the other answer works, but it leaves uneven vertical spacing and pushes the dropdown's children far to the right.

To fix the underlying problem with the dropdown being floated, add `clear: both` to both `.topnav.responsive a` and `.topnav.responsive .dropdown` (all within the `@media screen` rule):

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  ...
  .topnav.responsive a {
    ...
    clear: both;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown {
    ...
    clear: both;
  }
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is due to width issue in mobile screen display. Try adding width:100% property to dropdown. Add width property to following class:

```
.topnav.responsive .dropdown{
  float: left; 
  display:block;
  width:100%
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
  }
}
```

```css
body {margin:0;font-family:Arial}
.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #111;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 17px;    
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: #111;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.topnav a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child), .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: none;
  }
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown {float: none;}
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown-content {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
        <link REL=StyleSheet HREF="estilosMenu.css?<?php echo date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A'); ?>" TYPE="text/css">
        <script src="menu.js?<?php echo date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A'); ?>"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
         <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown 
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div> 
  <a href="#about">About</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;padding: 11.5px 16px;" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

How is this?